# How to create stream image in Angle Sharp

Tags: c#, anglesharp

I need to create a stream image from `IHtmlImageElement`.

In `HtmlUnit`, I'm using this:

```
HtmlImage image;
ImageReader reader = image.getImageReader();
```

So, how could I make this in `AngleSharp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngleSharp has only the knowledge that there is something like an `img` element with, e.g., a `src` attribute - it does not have the image stream (out of the box).

Getting an image stream can also be done fully independent of AngleSharp (see https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/blob/master/doc/Questions.md#how-to-download-a-picture for details).

Now if you want to get the `src` of an image just do something like

```
var src = document.QuerySelector<IHtmlImageElement>("img#my-awesome-img-element").Source;
```

where `document` is the document (`IHtmlDocument`) instance and `#my-awesome-img-element` is the ID of the image element. You can pick any CSS selector as you like.

Hope that helps!